# Alternate Proof of Kuratowski Complement-Closure Theorem

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am trying to prove Kuratowski Complement-Closure Theorem, which states that if we start with a set $S \subseteq X$ in a topological space $(X, \tau)$, we can get at most $14$ distinct sets using the operation of taking complements and closures. I am trying to prove the following fact first: if we start with a closed set, then the most number of sets we can form with these two operations is $6$. Here is a write-up of the proof.

We now show that $B, B ^ C, \overline{B ^ C}, \overline{B ^ C} ^ C, \overline{\overline{B ^ C} ^ C},$ and $\overline{\overline{B  ^ C} ^ C} ^ C$ are the only distinct sets that we can form. Let $F$ denote $\overline{\overline{B ^ C} ^ C} ^ C$. We now show that $\overline F = \overline{B ^ C}$. We see that 
$$B \ is \ closed \Rightarrow B ^ C = Int(B ^ C)$$
$$ \Rightarrow \overline{B ^ C} = B ^ C \cup Bd(B ^ C) $$
$$\Rightarrow \overline{B ^ C} ^ C = B \cap Bd(B ^ C) ^ C $$
$$= B \cap Bd(B) ^ C $$
$$= Int B \cup Bd(B) \cap Bd(B) ^ C = Int B$$
$$ \Rightarrow \overline{\overline{B ^ C} ^ C} = \overline {Int(B)} $$
$$\Rightarrow F = \overline{Int(B)} ^ C = Int(B) ^ C - Bd(Int B)$$.

Hence, we see that $x \in \overline F \Rightarrow $every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $Int(B) ^ C - Bd(Int B)$. We now show that $\overline{B ^ C} \subseteq \overline F$. We only need to show that $B ^ C \subseteq \overline F$. If $x \in B ^ C$, then $x \in Int(B ^ C)$, which means that there exists a neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $B ^ C$ (as $B ^ C$ is open). Therefore, we see clearly that $x \not \in Bd(Int B)$ and $x \in Int(B) ^ C$. Hence, we see that $B ^ C \subseteq \bar F$. We now show that $F \subseteq \overline{B ^ C}$. If $x \in Int (B) ^ C - Bd(Int B)$, we then see that there exists a neighborhood of $x$ that does not intersect $Int(B)$ and $x \not \in Int(B)$. If there exists a neighborhood of $x$ that only intersects $B$, then clearly $x \in Int(B)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we see that $x \in \overline{B ^ C}$, which means that $\overline F = \overline{B ^ C}$.

I was wondering if anyone could check to see if there is any error in the proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry there is some ambiguity in the proof on the second line. I am actually trying to prove that $\overline{B ^ C} = \overline{F}$.

Comment: You could use the techniques and ideas I wrote down in [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/24.pdf) which would probably be easier. What you have written is unreadable and unstructured.

Comment: It could be that $B^C$ is the last set you form (in the sequence you give), e.g. when we start with a clopen set $B$. So already the claim about $F$ is false.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That was really helpful as I did not think much into organizing the proof.

Comment: That being said, I do not think my claims about $F$ is false even if $B$ is clopen. Specifically, I meant to use $F$ to denote the last set in the six-set sequence. It may be the case that this sequence ends earlier, but I do not think that matters as $F$ is still used to denote the set $\overline{\overline{B ^ C} ^ C} ^ C$. I only used the assumption that $B$ is closed to show this, and I think all my deduction still follows if $B$ is open as well.

Comment: I have edited the problem according to your comment and added some of my modification. Thank you!